# Can use Thai font in Chapter or Section title but not in the Section's body

Tags: fonts, templates, books

All guru,

I'm using book template and can use Thai font in Chapter or Section title but when I typed Thai font in Section's body, it didn't show up. Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[p04]{elsevierbook}
\usepackage{geometry} % Required for adjusting page dimensions and margins
\geometry{
paper=a4paper, % Paper size, change to letterpaper for US letter size
top=5cm, % Top margin
bottom=3cm, % Bottom margin
left=3cm, % Left margin
right=3cm, % Right margin
headheight=14pt, % Header height
footskip=1.0cm, % Space from the bottom margin to the baseline of the footer
headsep=1cm, % Space from the top margin to the baseline of the header
%showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "th_TH"
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 2pt minus 1pt%
\setmainfont[Scale=1.1]{TH Sarabun New}
\setsansfont[Scale=1.1]{TH Sarabun New}
\setmonofont{TH Sarabun New}
\begin{document}
\Frontmatter
\Mainmatter
\chapter{\textbf{I can use Thai font here}}
\minitoc
\section{I also can use Thai font here too}
\lipsum[1] 
When I type Thai ไทย here, it doesn't show up.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `elsevierbook` document class is not made for use with XeLaTeX and `fontspec`. It loads the package `newtxtext` which you cannot easily use together with the `\setmainfont` macro.

Answer (score 1):

The `elsevierbook` document class is not made for use with XeLaTeX and `fontspec`. It loads the package `newtxtext` among other stuff which you cannot easily use together with the `\setmainfont` macro and the like provided by `fontspec`.

You set-up should rather be something like this (you may want to look for suitable Thai fonts that can be used with PDFLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[p04]{elsevierbook}
\usepackage{geometry} % Required for adjusting page dimensions and margins
\geometry{
paper=a4paper, % Paper size, change to letterpaper for US letter size
top=5cm, % Top margin
bottom=3cm, % Bottom margin
left=3cm, % Left margin
right=3cm, % Right margin
headheight=14pt, % Header height
footskip=1.0cm, % Space from the bottom margin to the baseline of the footer
headsep=1cm, % Space from the top margin to the baseline of the header
%showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[thai,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\Frontmatter
\Mainmatter
\chapter{\textbf{I can use Thai \textthai{ไทย} font here}}
\minitoc
\section{I also can use Thai \textthai{ไทย} font here too}
\lipsum[1] 
When I type Thai \textthai{ไทย} here, it shows up as well.
\end{document}
```

[image]